# move xsl sibling node inside parent?

Tags: xslt

How can I get from this:

```
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Component Feature="toplevel">
        <File Id="fil8A88F8B155E29670FCA1B83F0E99E635" />
        <TypeLib Id="{DC88F377-25DD-49C8-99D9-1FD8AE484362}" >
            <Interface Id="{5D12ED70-0B5A-49C4-A8A3-FC4C209295BA}" />
            <Interface Id="{73E8EDB7-4293-496D-8ABD-F973F002A033}" />
        </TypeLib>
        <TypeLib Id="{F3C9A192-17C2-4E25-ADB9-89FFEEC0403E}">
            <Interface Id="{89FF44C6-979D-49B6-AF56-EC9509001DE4}" />
        </TypeLib>
    </Component>
</Include>
```

to this:

```
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Component Feature="toplevel">
        <File Id="fil8A88F8B155E29670FCA1B83F0E99E635" >
            <TypeLib Id="{DC88F377-25DD-49C8-99D9-1FD8AE484362}" >
                <Interface Id="{5D12ED70-0B5A-49C4-A8A3-FC4C209295BA}" />
                <Interface Id="{73E8EDB7-4293-496D-8ABD-F973F002A033}" />
            </TypeLib>
            <TypeLib Id="{F3C9A192-17C2-4E25-ADB9-89FFEEC0403E}">
                <Interface Id="{89FF44C6-979D-49B6-AF56-EC9509001DE4}" />
            </TypeLib>
        </File>
    </Component>
</Include>
```

(move `<TypeLib>`s inside `<File>`...)

Thanks,

Comment: FYI: When I was formatting the code in your question, I noticed you were missing a closing quote in the `Id` attribute of your last `<Interface>` tag in each of your 2 examples. I corrected them. Hopefully that is not part of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: apologies, no... that was down to my sloppy copy/paste/format effort...

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:wi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::wi:TypeLib)] | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wi:File">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @* | following-sibling::wi:TypeLib" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Include xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Component Feature="toplevel">
    <File Id="fil8A88F8B155E29670FCA1B83F0E99E635">
      <TypeLib Id="{DC88F377-25DD-49C8-99D9-1FD8AE484362}">
        <Interface Id="{5D12ED70-0B5A-49C4-A8A3-FC4C209295BA}"></Interface>
        <Interface Id="{73E8EDB7-4293-496D-8ABD-F973F002A033}"></Interface>
      </TypeLib>
      <TypeLib Id="{F3C9A192-17C2-4E25-ADB9-89FFEEC0403E}">
        <Interface Id="{89FF44C6-979D-49B6-AF56-EC9509001DE4}"></Interface>
      </TypeLib>
    </File>
  </Component>
</Include>
```

This works like this:

1. the identity template (the first one) does explicitly exclude `<TypeLib>` children
2. a custom template handles `<File>` nodes, nesting all the following `<TypeLib>` nodes, i.e. making them children of `<File>`
3. this invokes the identity template for `<TypeLib>` nodes, which now perfectly copies them

Comment: I've tested it and it produces exactly the output I show in my answer. Have you tested with the stylesheet as I supplied it, or did you mix and match with your existing code?

Comment: mix and match... thing is, I have lots of other templates already defined... would it be useful if I upload the whole .xsl?